# json dictionary TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

```
import requests
    url = "**************"

querystring = {"domain":"gmail.com","username":"random","server":"server-1","type":"real"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "******************",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "*****************"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).text
```

response:

```
{"code":200,"msg":"OK","items":{"email":"vinhvivyanvinh72943@gmail.com","timestamp":1659215390}}
```

.

```
print(response['items'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Hello,
I do not encounter any problems when I use it in another dictionary.
How can I get email and timestamp into variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.json()` on request response:

```py
response = requests.request(
    "GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring
).json()                                             # <-- note the .json()

print(response["items"]["email"], response["items"]["timestamp"])
```